# Combining Stat_bin2d bins after sorting from bin counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find "zones" of different behavior of particles diffusing around on a surface. To do so I have produced this `stat_bin2d` histogram:

[image]

I then sort the bins and find the ones with 75% highest counts. The data from here on looks like this:

```
fill xbin ybin value      x     y count      density PANEL group          xmin      xmax       ymin
1 #01665E    1    1   297  4.088 4.088   297 0.0008302003     1    -1 -0.0000008176  8.176001 -8.176e-07
2 #19746C    2    1   635 12.264 4.088   635 0.0017750073     1    -1  8.1760008176 16.352001 -8.176e-07
3 #1A746C    3    1   647 20.440 4.088   647 0.0018085508     1    -1 16.3520008176 24.528001 -8.176e-07
4 #66B9B1    4    1  2288 28.616 4.088  2288 0.0063956170     1    -1 24.5280008176 32.704001 -8.176e-07
5 #CBEAE3    5    1  4057 36.792 4.088  4057 0.0113404800     1    -1 32.7040008176 40.880001 -8.176e-07
6 #2F877F    6    1  1092 44.968 4.088  1092 0.0030524536     1    -1 40.8800008176 49.056001 -8.176e-07
      ymax colour size linetype alpha
1 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
2 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
3 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
4 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
5 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
6 8.176001     NA  0.1        1    NA
```

My question:

I want to check if any of the chosen bins are located next to each other, and if so, i want to make a new "bin" containing the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax of the combined bins and save these bigger bins for later use.